# How to properly set POST value from AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass the value from jquery to php using AJAX, the problem is the value in the php is not properly set.

Here is my sample codes:

Button trigger to pass data into jquery.

```
<button class="btn btn-info add-percentage" 
  data-landing_id-percentage="'.$row['hidden_id'] .'" 
  data-toggle="add-percentage"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></button>
```

Below is the ajax and jquery code.

```
<script>
$(".add-percentage").click(function(){

    var landing_id = $(this).data('landing_id-percentage');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/readPercentage.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            landing_id: landing_id
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            alert('Email Sent'+msg);
            $('#add-percentage').modal('show');
            readRecords();
        }               
    });
  });
<script>
```

The result below in the php code is the landing_id is not properly set.

```
readPercentage.php

<?php
    $data = '
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id="ModalMyTable">
          <thead>
              <tr class="success">
                <th ><center>No.</center></th>
                <th ><center>Percentage ID</center></th>
                <th ><center>Landing ID</center></th>
                <th><center>Percentage</center></th>
                <th><center>Date Added</center></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>';
    if(isset($_POST['landing_id'])){

      $landing_id = $_POST['landing_id'];

      $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT
                  percentage.percent_id,
                  percentage.landing_id,
                  percentage.percentage,
                  percentage.date_recorded
                  FROM
                  percentage
                  WHERE percentage.landing_id = '$landing_id'");

      $number = 1;
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        $data .= '
          <tr>
            <td><center>' . $number . '</center></td>
            <td><center>' . $row['percent_id'] . '</center></td>
            <td><center>' . $row['landing_id'] . '</center></td>
            <td><center>' . $row['percentage'] . '%</center></td>
            <td><center>' . date("M. d, Y", strtotime($row['date_recorded'])) . '</center></td>
          </tr>';
        $number++;
      }
    }else{
      $data .='<tr><td colspan="6">Landing id is not properly set!</td></tr>';
    }
    $data .= '</table>
  <script>
    {
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#ModalMyTable").DataTable();
        readRecords();
        });
      }
  </script>
    ';

    echo $data;
?>
```

I hope some one can help me in my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you `console.log(landing_id)` before the ajax call does it return a value?

Comment: @redreddington yes it will return value.

Comment: And if you `var_dump($_POST)` before the `if(isset(` does that contain the value?

Comment: If it is in a form, the form will be submitted. You can add `type="button"` to it

Comment: ANd if you inspect the button, does it have a proper value in `data-landing_id-percentage="'.$row['hidden_id'] .'" `

Comment: @mplungjan it has a proper value, when I alert the landing_id it will display.. and when I echo the landing_id  in the php it will display too.

Comment: @redreddington Undefined index: landing_id.

Comment: @UnusInstarOmnium and that appears in the console window when you do the POST, not when you just visit the page?

Comment: @redreddington it will not appear when I just click the button.. not in visiting the page.

Comment: I've noticed that when working with some JS libraries sending a HTTP POST your data ends up in `php://input` as opposed to the `$_POST` array.  Try `$postData=file_get_contents("php://input");` and if you get a string then convert to object or array using `json_decode`

Comment: @ivanivan i cannot get the string..

Comment: @mplungjan the index of the post is undefined but the data from the ajax was successfully ssent. What will I do in my code to solve this problem.

Comment: I do not spot anything obvious.sorry